# Generic Route in Symfony 2.8 - Why does "empty" page with trailing slash does not match?

Tags: symfony, routes

I am using Symfony 2.8 and have configured a generic route:

```
// routes.xml
<route id="info_page" path="/info/{page}" methods="GET">
    <default key="_controller">MyBundle:Info:showPage</default>
    <default key="page">overview</default>
</route>

// Controller
public function showPageAction(Request $request, $page) {
    switch ($page) {
        case "page1":
            $template = "page1.html.twig";
            break;

        ...

        default: 
            $template = "overview.html.twig";
            break; 
    }

    $response = $this->render($template, $variables);
    return $response;
}
```

This works fine for all sort of routes like `/info/page1`, `/info/pageN`, `/info/overview`, etc. and `/info` is shown as default/overview page (as expected).

However, using `/info/` (trailing slash) leads to error 404. Why is that? Why does `/info` work while `/info/` does not?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Symfony compiles the routes to regular expressions, so `/info/(.*)` won't match `/info/` and will throw error 404.

I'm confused how `/info` works for you, I'm guessing you might have that route defined elsewhere.

Offtopic, although `/info/` and `/info` are usually used interchangeably on the internet, they are **different** routes and Symfony treated them as such.

It's not until newer versions of Symfony (4.1) that these two variants can be used - read [here](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-smarter-url-redirections)